# Casting partial type to full type doesn't give an error

Tags: typescript

Why doesn't this code give an error? Some properties are missing.

```
type Todo = {
  id: number
  text: string
  isCompleted: boolean
}

let todo: Todo = {
  id: 123,
} as Todo
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKg9gEzlAvFA3gKClAlggLigDsBXAWwCMIAnbKYCAD2CIGdgbdiBze3NgGE45MABsIjQlEpw4EgIbFMAX0yYJwBojhF4SVBn7SAjACYAzABpVUBW1g7MQA)

Interestingly, if I replace `id: 123` for example to `id: "abc"`, this gives an error about incorrect type (obviously), but also mentions that other props are missing.

**EDIT**:

I was trying to make this function:

```
function doSmth<T extends Todo>(fn: (t: Partial<T>) => void) {
  fn({id: 123})
}
```

But TS gave an error, so I add a cast:

```
function doSmth<T extends Todo>(fn: (t: Partial<T>) => void) {
  fn({id: 123} as Partial<T>)
}
```

And it was fine. But then I tried to change the cast to see what happens:

```
function doSmth<T extends Todo>(fn: (t: Partial<T>) => void) {
  fn({id: 123} as T)
}
```

And this was fine too.

So I thought this is weird and that's why I asked.

Comment: Downcasting (or, more accurately, *asserting* a narrower type) is allowed on purpose.  That's the main purpose of the feature.  Don't use `as` if you don't want that to happen.

Comment: If I correctly understand the linked question - it's quite opposite. It's about allowing extra properties on an object, which already has base type properties (widening?). In my case an object is missing type properties. I thought that `as Todo` cast should fail and if I wanted to enforce it, I should use `as unknown as Todo` cast. Guess I was wrong. Anyway, I'll edit the question, to show what I was doing.

Comment: Oh, if the linked question is upcasting then it *is* the opposite, sorry.  Hold on.... okay, found the one I intended instead.  TS allows type assertions to both upcast (safe) and downcast (unsafe). Since `{id: number}` is a supertype of `Todo` then it's allowed.  The only reason you'd need something like `as unknown as` would be if you're trying to, uh, *side*-cast, since `unknown` is a universal supertype, so `X as unknown` is always an upcast and `unknown as Y` is always a downcast.

Comment: I thought that `as unknown as` is the only force-cast, and that `as T` serves more as a compiler hint or soft-cast. I understand it now, thanks.